# Web Page downloading questions

Tags: javascript, html, download

Is there a client side way to open a dialog box to select a folder to download files to?
I would like the functionality of a "create new folder" function in the dialog box. And once they select a folder to to download to, can I send the directory to a javascript function as a string?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript operates in a SandBox~ it doesn't have access to the file system.

Comment: Then what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I believe Flash has file system access~ but that's a whole new set of conventions to learn~~